# Filtering the whole first two columns in dplyr

Tags: r

I have multiple time series data and I want to apply Jag code and how can I use the whole first two columns in filtering because the combination of the first two columns is a unique combination that I want to use that for JAG code?

```
    Site    SP   Year   Abun    
     A3   BG    1957    81  
     A3   BG    1958    45  
     A3   BG    1959    96  
     A3   BG    1960    44  
     A3  BG    1961     24  
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
…………………………..
  A3    BD  1957    135 
  A3    BD  1958    91  
  A3    BD  1959    171 
  A3    BD  1960    88
```

I tried for only one column as follows:

```
for (SP in c("BG”  “BD", "CD", "DC", "AC", "DB")){
y <- data %>% 
    filter(SP == sp, year > 1956, year < 1998) %>% 
    select(Abun)
```

}

I want to filter or uniquely separate the data taking the whole combination of the first two columns (Site and SP), any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to separate as multiple datasets, use `split` to return a `list` of datasets

```
data1 <- subset(data, SP %in% c("BG”  “BD", "CD", "DC", "AC", "DB") & 
                year > 1956 & year < 1998))
lst1 <- split(data1, data1[c("Site", "SP")], drop = TRUE)
```

Comment: I want to take the whole element in the first two columns and there are other categorical variables that I didn't mention under SP, but they are uniquely combined with the site, does the code work for that?

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser your condition with `year` was confusing.  I thought you want to create multiple dataset for each unique combination of 'SP' 'Site' and that should only have some values from 'SP'.  Therefore, I subset the data first and then useed the `split`

Comment: If you don't want to use `year`, then you may just do `split(data, data[c("Site", "SP")], drop = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, by the way you are right, I just cut the year off, it goes from 1957 to 1998. One thing to clarify, I don't want to use subset since I am going to use the whole column under "Site", "SP" and ("year" )combination.

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser so then the `split(data, data[c("Site", "SP")], drop = TRUE)` should work?

Comment: Thanks@akrun, I will try it!

Comment: would you help me out how to prepare the above split multiple time series data for Jags code, the first 30 of the first time series in to training set (1957 - 1987) and the rest (1988 to 1998) to testing set?

Comment: can you help me out in JAGS code, I will consider your service,  I know you are computer geek and helpful?